# Efficient algorithm to fulfill order for items

Tags: algorithms

Here is a problem I encountered at work, basically, the problem is to find warehouses to fulfill an order.

For example, I have an order that comes with 10 items (and their desired quantity) shipped to the same location, and each of the items can be supplied by 5 different warehouses. Some of the items can be supplied by the same warehouse if the warehouse has enough inventories for those items. Of course, ordering an item costs money as well as shipping it. Say, I need 5 items of A and 3 items of B, and I decided that they should be supplied by warehouse 1, and the prices for ordering them are $p_A$ and $p_B$, then the ordering cost is $5p_A + 3p_B$, to calculate the cost for shipping, I have the volumes of them, which are $v_A$ and $v_B$, the cost for shipping is then $T*D*(5v_A+3v_B)$, where $T$ is the cost of shipment per volume per mile and $D$ is the distance between warehouse 1 and the destination.

I want to find the best combination of items and warehouses **so that the average of the ratios between shipping cost and ordering cost is as low as possible**. The naive brute force searching seems very inefficient because I need to loop through each possible combination of items and warehouses, how would I model such a problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not totally clear to me which parameters are dependent on the choice of warehouse. An average of ratios seems a very odd way of measuring things, but it is also unclear which ratios you mean exactly. Is it calculated per warehouse? What if nothing is ordered from a particular warehouse so its ratio is 0/0?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis items that are supplied by the same warehouse has the same distance to the destination and hence uses the same unit price of shipping (per volume per mile). So yes, the ratio is calculated per warehouse. The usage of the ratio is a choice of the business department, so I cannot change that. If nothing is ordered from a particular warehouse, the ratio is counted as 0.